# Jquery Get data is not returning to the redirected page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have three php pages and two javascript/jquery functions.
 
**Search.php:**

In this page jquery Get data is sending data to *LikeMail.php* by clicking img tag embedded in anchor tag. Both and also other html contents inside while loop are generated dynamically. After sending jquery get data to *LikeMail.php* it then calls that php page by ajax call. Both jquery and ajax are working fine in this page. Jquery sending data correctly and receives data by ajax correctly.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("db.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="user2.js"></script>

    <style>
        p.col-lg-2{
          font-family: "Comic Sans MS";
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>



<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar nav-top navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="link one"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="link">
                        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Blog</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="link"><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li class="link"><a href="#">Terms & Cond</a></li>
                    <li class="link"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="one"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <!--Navbar-->



    <div class="row topsecond">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h3 class="heading">Ads</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Ads-->


    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-5">
                <a type="button" href="userOwnProfile.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">My Profile</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-5">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Women List</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-5">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Message List</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-5">
                <a href="#">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">New Likes</button>
                </a></div>
            </a>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-5">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">New Message</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
<div class="row">
        <h3 class="heading"><u>MEN'S LIST - Filter Search Result by:</u></h3>
</div>
        <div class="row">
<!--            <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-lg-1" for="pwd"> State Living: </label>-->
            <!--<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-1 col-lg-2">
                <select class="form-control col-lg-1">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>-->

            <div class="control-label col-xs-12 col-lg-2">
                <label for="age from">
                    Country
                </label>
                <select class="form-control col-lg-2">
                    <option selected>All</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <!--<label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-lg-1" for="pwd">State Living:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-lg-2">
                <select class="form-control col-lg-3">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>-->
            <div class="control-label col-xs-12 col-lg-2">
                <label for="age from">
                    State Origin
                </label>
                <select class="form-control col-lg-2">
                    <option selected>Choose</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <!--<label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-lg-1" for="pwd">State Living:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-lg-2">
                <select class="form-control ">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>-->

            <div class="control-label col-xs-12 col-lg-2">
                <label for="age from">
                    State Living
                </label>
                <select class="form-control col-lg-2">
                    <option selected>Choose</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <!--<label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-lg-1" for="pwd">State Living:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-lg-2">
                <select class="form-control ">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>-->


            <div class="control-label col-xs-12 col-lg-2">
                <label for="age from">
                    Marital Status
                </label>
                <select class="form-control col-lg-2">
                    <option selected>Choose</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <!--<label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-lg-1" for="pwd">State Living:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 col-lg-2">
                <select class="form-control col-lg-3">
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
-->


            <div class="control-label col-xs-12 col-lg-2">
                <label for="age from">
                    Marital Status
                </label>
                <select class="form-control col-lg-2">
                    <option selected>Choose</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                    <option>5</option>
                </select>
            </div>


        <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-1">
                <label for="age from">
                    Age from
                </label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-1">

                <label for="age to">
                    Age to
                </label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text">
                </div>


        </div>
    </div>



    <div class="col-lg-4">

    </div>

<div class="row">



    <div class="col-lg-2">


    </div>



    <div class="col-lg-12">


        <?php
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user");

        while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

        if ($record == FALSE) {
            die(mysqli_error("error message for the user"));
        }

        ?>


        <div style="border: 1px dotted black;" class="row" id="call">

            <div style=" border: 1px solid white" class="col-lg-2">
                <!--<img src="images/team-hire.jpg" style="background-size: cover" width="85%" height="90%">-->



                <a class="profile" href="<?php echo "viewProfile.php?id=" . $record['user_id'];?>" >
                    <img class="img-rounded"
                         src=" <?php echo "../shadi/images/" . $record['user_photo1'] ?>"
                         id="<?php echo $record['user_id']; ?>"alt="" width="70%" height="20%">

                </a>





            </div>

            <p class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-6">
                <?php echo $record['user_educationLevel'];  ?>
            </p>

            <p class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12">
                <?php echo $record['user_career'] ?>
            </p>

            <p class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12">

                <?php echo $record['user_stateLiving'] ?>
            </p>

            <p class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12">
                <?php echo $record['user_stateOfOrigin'] ?>
            </p>

            <p class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12">
                <?php echo $record['user_religion'] ?>
            </p>

        </div>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>

</div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

---

**LikeMail.php:**

jquery get data is being sent in this page. After some processing, it then shows out put which then returns through ajax call in desired pages

**viewProfile.php:**

This is the page where problem exists. it is basically redirected page. Its url is stored in anchor tag in *Search.php* page. In this page ajax is returning wrong data from *LikeMail.php* as jquery get data which we have sent earlier through *Search.php* is not returning in this page.

```
    <html>
<head>

</head>
</html>
<?php
session_start();
include("db.php");
if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    header("Location:Login.php");


}
else {
    $user1 = $_SESSION['user_id'];

    if ($user_id == "") {

        header("location:index.php");
    } else {


//echo $user_id;
//$user_id = 14;
        $user_email = $_SESSION['user_email'];

        /*$sql = "UPDATE user SET user_onlineStatus= . NOW() . WHERE user_id=14";

        $setLogged = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);*/
//echo $_SESSION['user_id'];

        ?>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>User's Own Profile</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
            <script src="js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="bootstrap-3.3.6-dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <!--<script src="js/custom.js"></script>-->

            <script src="test.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>

        <div class="container">
        <nav class="navbar nav-top navbar-inverse">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="link one"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="link">
                            <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Blog</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="link"><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li class="link"><a href="#">Terms & Cond</a></li>
                        <li class="link"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="one"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>


        <!--Navbar-->


        <div class="row topsecond">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h3 class="heading">Ads</h3>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--Ads-->


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-5">
                    <a type="button" href="userOwnProfile.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">My Profile</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-5">
                    <a type="button" href="Search.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Find People</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-5">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Message List</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-5">
                    <a href="#">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">New Likes</button>
                    </a></div>
                </a>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-5">
                    <button href="index.php" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">New Message</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <!--Links-->


        <div class="col-lg-8 left">

        <div class="row">
        <div class="row ">
        <?php
        //           include("db.php");
        //$user_id = 14;
        $photo = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id='$user_id'");

        while ($recordPhoto = mysqli_fetch_array($photo)) {

            if ($recordPhoto == FALSE) {
                die(mysqli_error("error message for the user"));

            }

            ?>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 img">

                <img class="img-rounded" src="<?php echo "../shadi/images/" . $recordPhoto['user_photo1'] ?>" alt=""
                     width="100%" height="40%">
            </div>

            <?php if($recordPhoto['user_photo2']!=""){

             ?>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 img">
                <img class="img-rounded" src="<?php echo "../shadi/images/" . $recordPhoto['user_photo2'] ?>" alt="" width="100%" height="40%">
            </div><?php }
            else
            {
                echo "";
            }
            if($recordPhoto['user_photo2']!=""){


            ?>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 img">
                <img class="img-rounded" src="<?php echo "../shadi/images/" . $recordPhoto['user_photo3'] ?>" alt="" width="100%" height="40%">
            </div>
            <?php }
            else
            {
                echo "";
            }
            ?>
            </div>


            <div class="row upload">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">

                    <div id="Like"></div>//This is the div where ajax data is returning through LikeMail.php
                </div>


                <a href="indexchat.php?chat=<?php echo $user_id; ?>">
                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="btn btn-lg btn-info edit">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Messages
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>

            </div>
            </div>
            <?php
            $res = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id=$user_id");

            while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

                if ($record == FALSE) {
                    die(mysqli_error("error message for the user"));

                }
                ?>
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="row">
                        <h3 class="heading col-sm-4">PROFILE</h3>

                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <h3><?php echo $record['user_name']; ?></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h4 class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">Gender :</h4>

                            <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-4 col-xs-8">
                                <h5><?php echo $record['user_gender']; ?></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h4 class=" col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4">Date of Birth :</h4>

                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <h5><?php echo $record['user_dob']; ?></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h4 class=" col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4">Age :</h4>

                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-4 col-xs-12">
                                <h5>31 years</h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h4 class=" col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4">Height :</h4>

                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <h5><?php echo $record['user_height']; ?></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h4 class=" col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4">Weight :</h4>

                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <h5><?php echo $record['user_weight']; ?></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h4 class=" col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4">Race :</h4>

                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <h5><?php echo $record['user_race']; ?></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h4 class=" col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4">Religion :</h4>

                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <h5><?php echo $record['user_religion']; ?></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>

                    <div class="">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h4 class=" col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4">Country :</h4>

                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <h5> <?php echo $record['user_country']; ?></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h4 class=" col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4">State Origin :</h4>

                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <h5>  <?php echo $record['user_stateOfOrigin']; ?>
                                </h5></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h4 class=" col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4">State Living :</h4>

                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <h5> <?php echo $record['user_stateLiving']; ?></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h4 class=" col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4">Marital Stauts :</h4>

                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <h5><?php echo $record['user_maritalStatus']; ?></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h4 class=" col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4">Career :</h4>

                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <h5><?php echo $record['user_career']; ?></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h4 class=" col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4">Educational Level :</h4>

                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <h5><?php echo $record['user_educationLevel']; ?></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>

                    <div class="">
                        <div class="row">
                            <h4 class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4">Relations for</h4>

                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                                <h5><?php echo $record['user_relationshipfor']; ?></h5>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

               </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <h4 class=" col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-xs-4">Self Summary : <br>
                        </h4>

                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-6">
                            <h5><?php echo $record['user_selfSummary']; ?></h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>


                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">

                        </div>
                        <!--<div class="col-sm-8">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning">Submit</button>
    <div class="respond"></div>
</body>
    </html>
    <?php
}
    ?>
```

**user2.js:**

This is jquery function of get in user2.js page

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.profile').on('click', function (e) {

        //Get the href Link
        var href = $(this).attr('href');

        e.preventDefault();
        $.get("LikeMail.php",
            {user2: $(this).find(".img-rounded").attr("id")}, function (returnedData) {

                // Do whatever you want with returend data
                console.log(returnedData),

                function(){
                    console.log('error');
                }


            }).done(function () {
            //Redirecting to anchor destination.
            window.location.href = href;

        });

    });

});
```

---

**test.js:**

This ajax function in test.js

```
function like()
    {
    var req  = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function()

    {
        if(req.readyState==4 && req.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById('Like').innerHTML=req.responseText;

        }
    }
    req.open('GET','LikeMail.php','true');
    req.send();
}
setInterval(function(){like()},1000);
```

I want ti know why jquery get data is not receiving in vieProfile.php page after redirecting through anchor tag in Search.php

**Update:**
Ajax is returning in `<div id="Like"></div>` in viewProfile.php